# Ajax call to Github API fails

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

So I'm a little new at this, a the code I have so far is not working yet, but if anyone can tell me what i missing I would be grateful.

Basically, I'm trying to make a call to github's api, which returns json data. I'd eventually like to parse it and display only specific information, but at the present I'm just trying to get the data to show in my browser. Here is what I have so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$.ajax({
    url: "https://api.github.com/repos/VonC/gitolite/git/refs/tags",
    dataType: "jsonp", // I'm under the impression i should use jsonp, since this is a cross domain call
    success: function (returndata)
    {
        $('.result').html(returndata);
        alert('Load was performed.');
      }  
    });
 });
</script>
```

The url definitely works: when you call it using CURL, the following json data is returned:

```
[
{
"object": {
  "type": "commit",
  "sha": "9accde83842523e18de320fc2f0a8efeaebef27b",
  "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/jeffreycwitt/jeffswebpage/git/commits/9accde83842523e18de320fc2f0a8efeaebef27b"
 },
"url": "https://api.github.com/repos/jeffreycwitt/jeffswebpage/git/refs/heads/master",
"ref": "refs/heads/master"
 } 
]
```

Thanks for any advice you can give me.

Comment: Ehats the question ? You make a call and you get the json returned ... thats good isn't it ?

Comment: dataType: "jasonp" looks a bit wrong. I'm sure Jason P likes being a data type :D

Comment: @NimChimpsky - well, it would seem good, except it doesn't work in my browser -- does it work for you? check out my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Geoff16W/JSGnF/2/ - let me know if you can make it work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dataType` should probably be `jsonp` and not `jasonp`. Even better, it should simply be `json` as you are not making a JSONP call.

Another thing you should watch out for is that `returndata` is going to be the actual, parsed JavaScript object that comes out of the JSON representation, not the JSON object as a string. This means that you cannot put it straight into the `.result` div.

The following seems to work for me:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://api.github.com/repos/VonC/gitolite/git/refs/tags",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (returndata)
    {
        $("#result").html(returndata[0]["object"]["sha"]);
        alert('Load was performed.');
    }  
});
```

Comment: ahh, yes indeed that is wrong. I'll edit the question. Now the alert fires, but I still don't get any data entering the "div" and showing up in my browser.

Comment: In case data that returned from server is simple text, it can be injected into div directly, otherwise, you must take required text from Javascript object created on base of JSON string that the server returned.

Comment: tada - it works. Thanks very much. I guess i'm still confused about why I'm not using jsonp -- i thought I was supposed to use this for sites not under the same domain.

Comment: Any reason this .parseJson shouldn't work:success: 
    `function (returndata)
        {
         var obj = $.parseJson(returndata);
        $(".result").html(obj.type);
        alert('Load was performed.');
        }  
     });`

Comment: `returndata` is already parsed, so you couldn't parse it again.

Answer (score 1):

the returned data is not html, its a json object you have to reference the fields directly or loop through them.

You can access the data like so (although worth noting that using property name object is rather confusing, it can be any string))

```
returndata[0].object.sha
```

(And change jason to json)

Comment: Any reason this .parseJson shouldn't work:
`success: function (returndata) { 
var obj = $.parseJson(returndata); 
$(".result").html(obj.type); 
alert('Load was performed.'); 
} 
});`

Comment: @jeff you already have a json object, returndata. Just use that