# XDomainRequest - not calling...not doing anything

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer, xdomainrequest

I've a problem...I use jQuery ajax to call a web service that returns XML.  The jQuery ajax stuff works awesome for every browser except for ie.

So for ie browsers, I am using XDomainRequest.  Here is the code:

```
if ($.browser.msie && window.XDomainRequest) {
    // Use Microsoft XDR
    var xdr = new XDomainRequest();
    xdr.open("get", theUserUrl);
    xdr.timeout = 95000;
    xdr.onerror = function () {
        console.log('we have an error!');
    }
    xdr.onprogress = function () {
        console.log('this sucks!');
    };
    xdr.ontimeout = function () {
        console.log('it timed out!');
    };
    xdr.onopen = function () {
        console.log('we open the xdomainrequest');
    };
    xdr.onload = function () {
        // XDomainRequest doesn't provide responseXml, so if you need it:
        var xml2 = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
        xml2.async = false;
        xml2.loadXML(xdr.responseText);
        console.log('do we get any response text at all?: ' + xdr.responseText);
        ParseOwnershipObjects(xml2);
        //AddServiceRequestsToMap(xml2, map, spinner);
    };
    xdr.send();
}
```

- This exact code works fine elsewhere in the application with a
  different url.

  The url is fine, it returns exactly what it should in the browser
  (and hence why the jquery ajax call works).  Couple of things to
  note:

  I am integrating my own html/javascript with another guy's asp.net
  project.

In the `global.asax.cs` file, I have:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,OPTIONS");
}
```

so I don't think that it's a header problem.

None of my handlers fire.  Not the onprogress, ontimeout, onerror...nothing!
I don't have time to convert the web service to JSON.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, there were special characters in the url parameters that were not being correctly dealt with by the XDomainRequest object.  Instead of the GET request, I am going to use the POST request on internet explorer-only queries.

EDIT - I ended up switching the web service over to return output in JSON format, thus negating the need for the XDomainRequest.  Using JSON speeds things up a bit too, I recommend it!

Comment: Can you clarify how changing the response format negated the need for XDomainRequest? It's still cross-domain, correct?

Comment: Using JSON allows you to circumvent use of the XDomainRequest object for IE-specific cases, and use jQuery ajax for everything.  The cross-domain problem disappears.  Check out this answer for more details on using JSON with jquery Ajax: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8894013/575861

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer - I actually haven't used 'XDomainRequest' - when using jQ I set data to `jsonp` for xdomain requests...

When debugging - are you using IE Dev tools (`F12`)? If not, the error is likely `console.log`

EDIT:
mea culpa, disregard the `jsonp` stuff - missed the part you mentioned `XML`

---

Update:

Out of curiosity I'm trying `XDomainRequest`. I copied your code and just added a value for `theUserUrl`.

- as above/expected, unless I have Internet Explorer Developer tools running, `console` is `undefined` - and may give the impression that "none of your handlers are firing".
- Once I have the IE dev tools enabled (docked or otherwise) `xdr.onerror` fires. `we have an error` is logged in the IE console. So while there **is** an error, the handler *does* fire.

[image: Internet Explorer Dev Tools Consoloe]

A quick read on `XDomainRequest` requires the **responding** server to have the *Access-Control-Allow-Origin* header. I'm calling my own server and I know I **don't** have this header set, so without further debugging, it would be a good guess that's why `xdr.onerror` is being fired.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I have been using F12, specifically the console.  When I leave the dev tools undocked in the window, whenever I open the test page (i.e. http://localhost:28730/Test.aspx), it always crashes the dev tools (in that it closes the window).  When I dock the dev tools into the browser window, I don't get any output.  I also commented out all off the console.log commands to no avail.

Comment: Thanks.  I don't think that the console had anything to do with it, because I commented them out multiple times and was always running the developer tools.  Thanks for the help, though. I appreciate it!